# Vidyo.io call recording issue

Tags: video-conferencing, call-recording, vidyo

I'm developing a web application integrating Vidyo and I need to record video calls. I followed the [documentation guide](https://support.vidyo.io/hc/en-us/articles/115006198708-Integrate-the-Media-Bridge-Docker-Image-with-your-Vidyo-io-based-Application) and installed a Media Bridge Docker image in my server. I don't face problems on connecting with the media bridge, but effectively it doesn't record video nor audio. The output .flv file shows only a 10 seconds black screen with display names of the call particpants.

My configuration file is:

```
width=1280
height=720
fps=30
kbps=2000
layout=1
maxParticipants=8
overlay=1
videoCodec=H264
audioCodec=AAC
maxCallDuration=180
presentationAllowed=1
presWidth=1280
presHeight=720
presFps=5
presKbps=300
destination="flv:/opt/vidyo/recordingTest.flv"
resourceId="test_recording"
token=<TOKEN HERE>
host="prod.vidyo.io"
mediaPorts="50000-50100"
publicIp="127.0.0.1"
log=debug
```

And the errors in the output log file are:

```
[1050]: LmiAudioProcessing   ERROR [System thread]      LmiAudioProcessing.c:1208 LmiAudioProcessingSetVoiceProcessing scip_xmpp_audio_processing audio processing: special voice processing should be set to off prior to setting voice processing off.
[1050]: LmiAudioProcessing   ERROR [System thread]      LmiAudioProcessing.c:1219 LmiAudioProcessingSetVoiceProcessing scip_xmpp_audio_processing audio processing: unable to set voice processing off.
[1050]: LmiTransport         ERROR [System thread]      LmiTcpTransport.c:1435 LmiTcpTransportConstructAddressFromString Error resolving address roni.eng.vidyo.com:443: UnknownHost
[1050]: LmiSignaling         ERROR [System thread]      LmiStackConnection.c:36 LmiStackConnectionConstructOutbound Could not create connection to ed3df5eef18e3b0d
[1050]: XmppGateway          ERROR [System thread]      xmpp.c:1010 makeXmppCall failed: LmiUserLogin
[1050]: leg                  ERROR [System thread]      leg.c:845 legStart epMakeCall failed.  protocol: xmpp dest: room:demoRoom~token:<TOKEN>~server:roni.eng.vidyo.com config: addOverlay:on~caFile:/opt/vidyo/conf/openssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt~dropCall:on
[1050]: gwCall               ERROR [System thread]      call.c:1744 main failed: legStart 0
[126]: LmiAudioProcessing    ERROR [System thread]      LmiAudioProcessing.c:1208 LmiAudioProcessingSetVoiceProcessing scip_xmpp_audio_processing audio processing: special voice processing should be set to off prior to setting voice processing off.
[126]: LmiAudioProcessing    ERROR [System thread]      LmiAudioProcessing.c:1219 LmiAudioProcessingSetVoiceProcessing scip_xmpp_audio_processing audio processing: unable to set voice processing off.
[126]: writer                ERROR [System thread]      writer.c:876 writerUpdateStats failed: Assign audio stats
[126]: rtmp                  ERROR [System thread]      rtmp.c:662 endpointGetStats failed: Update stats
[126]: leg                   ERROR [System thread]      leg.c:1567 legGetStats failed: epGetStats failed
[126]: ScipXmppCommon        ERROR xmpp                 scip_xmpp_common.c:269 sxcRemoteSourceAdded We already have video remote source - skip this one
[126]: LmiRtp                ERROR xmpp                 LmiRtpSessionInline.h:294 LmiRtpSessionGetActiveRtpDestination 3LI/IGh+pOy/zbUmmgAa conn 1: Can't get active RTP destination from stopped session
[126]: LmiRtp                ERROR xmpp                 LmiRtpSessionInline.h:294 LmiRtpSessionGetActiveRtpDestination 3LI/IGh+pOy/zbUmmgAa conn 2: Can't get active RTP destination from stopped session
[126]: XmppGateway           ERROR xmpp                 xmpp.c:586 selectedParticipantListChanged failed: selected_participants_do_show_selected_n
[126]: leg                   ERROR videoRenderer        leg.c:388 epCaptureVideo leg: xmpp get video frame failed
[126]: gwCall                ERROR gw-tp-1              call.c:1472 peerCallEndTask legEndCall failed
```

Answer (score 3):

In case if this helps you try this, this worked for me.You don't need SIP configuration

```
#main video/audio settings
width=1280
height=720
fps=30
kbps=2000
layout=1
maxParticipants=8
overlay=1
videoCodec=H264
audioCodec=PCM
maxCallDuration=180   # duration in minutes

#Presentation settings
presentationAllowed=1 #0 - ignore presentations 1 - replace main video with presentation
presWidth=1280
presHeight=720
presFps=5
presKbps=300
destination="flv:/opt/vidyo/<call_id>.flv"

#vidyo.io connection info
resourceId="<room_id>"
token="<call_token>"
host="prod.vidyo.io"
```

Comment: @heliosophist is your problem resolved, if yes please accept my answer, thanks.